# javascript openlayers3 object methods

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code :

```
let text = new ol.style.Text({
    font: '14px Arial',
    text: 'string'
});

let icon = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
        anchor: [0.5, 46],
        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
        anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
        src: './img/icon.png'
    })),
    text: text
});
```

why is this working ? :

```
text.setText("otherString"); 
icon.setText(text); 
feature.setStyle(icon) 

// the name of someFeature is changed to someOtherString as supposed to
```

but this is not working :

```
feature.setStyle(icon.setText(text.setText("anotherString"))); 
//name is not changed.
```

This is probably something about Javascript that I don't understand. Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: Probably because `someText.setText()` return type is not what is expected to be input type of `someIcon.setText()`. `someIcon.setText(someText);` doing this you are passing a object `someText` and not the output of `someText.setText("someOtherString")`

Comment: Yes. You are right. That was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: okay cool! I am adding it as answer please accept it to help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because `someText.setText()` return type is not what is expected to be input type of `someIcon.setText()`.

If you try to do like: `someIcon.setText(someText);`

You are passing a object `someText` and not the output of `someText.setText("someOtherString")`.

That is the reason why `someIcon.setText(someText);` is working but `someIcon.setText(someText.setText("someOtherString"))` is not working.

Comment: could you set some text to explain sometext so that text of sometext is textually texted in sometext? Holy crap. that's a lot of some's being texted. The programmers tonguetwister.

Comment: Yes, I know.. but I am trying to explain based on code snippet that is shared.

Comment: For me it's ok, I understood exactly where the problem was. I've built myself a function that changes the string of someText whenever I need. Thanks again.